# MongoDB replica set not connected in EC2 instance

Tags: mongodb

I've taken mongodb instance and connected network load balancer and configured 3 instance replica set.
When running as a single instance its working fine but while doing with the replica set, the 1st API hit is working fine but when I give the next hit it fails.

After continuous hits of multiple times it again gets the result. I've tried rs.secondaryOk() on the mongodb instance running on the replica set. While doing sometimes it works fine but after sometime it again fails with error of **not primary secondary=false**

Please let me know you thoughts on the same

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shall not use 3th party load balancer with mongoDB , you need to access the replicaSet from the driver as replicaSet ( the driver will automatically identify who is the PRIMARY member and forward the writes only to PRIMARY )  -> in mongoDB replicaSet architecture the SECONDARY members do not accept writes  , if you dont want your driver to deal with who is PRIMARY & who is SECONDARY you need to deploy sharded cluster with routing services ( mongoses ) where you can connect the drivers then

Comment: Thank you R2D2..I'll research and do as per your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection URI to your replicaSet mongoDB must look something like that:

`mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017,mongodb2.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl`

If you connect individually to every member via 3th party loadbalancer it will not work as expected ...

Comment: Okay where the DB name should be written. For the previous URL I've written in the connection URL itself at the last but now can I add & at the end of the string and add the DBName

Comment: 27017/theDBName?replcaSet=myRepl

Comment: It worked 
Thank you so much

Comment: Could you please help with the below question too if you have any idea on the same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787420/unable-to-connect-to-mongoshell-when-added-tls-ssl-certificates-in-ec2-instance