# Unable to connect to mongoshell when added TLS/SSL certificates in EC2 instance

Tags: mongodb, ssl-certificate

I've configured the mongodb using TLS/SSL certificates in the EC2 instance
The configuration looks as follows:

```
#ssl certificates
net:
   tls:
      mode: requireTLS
      certificateKeyFile: /var/lib/mongo/cert/PEG.pem
      CAFile: /var/lib/mongo/cert/peg.ca-bundle

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

After configuring I'm trying to connect to mongo shell using the following command:

```
mongo domain.com --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile /var/lib/mongo/cert/PEG.pem --tlsCAFile /var/lib/mongo/cert/peg.ca-bundle
```

But unable to enter into the shell and got the following error:

```
"error":"SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to verify the first certificate"}}
```

Could anyone help how to approach this error

Thanks in Advance

Comment: mongosh --tls --host hostname.example.com --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/client.pem --tlsCAFile /etc/ssl/caToValidateServerCertificates.pem

Comment: Thank you R2D2 
but I tried the above also but got the following error
[root@ip-0-0-0-0 tmp]# mongosh --tls --host domain.com --tlsCertificateKeyFile /var/lib/mongo/cert/PEG.pem --tlsCAFile /var/lib/mongo/cert/peg.ca-bundle
Current Mongosh Log ID: 61e96db741cc0ac7621c4d66741258
Connecting to:          mongodb://domain.com:27017/?directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.1.9
MongoServerSelectionError: unable to verify the first certificate

Comment: maybe something with the certs ...

Comment: Okay Thank you then I'll check with the certs